# Run a perl script with the ending .pl

Tags: linux, perl, unix, console, raspberry-pi

I have a question to perl scripts. I can write and understand C and C++ codes but have no experience in perl.

I have a perl script with the extension .pl and want to run it on a Raspberry Pi Model B.

I get the script (its a part of the Raspberry Pi B extension 'Busware SD0' Firmware) from this [link](https://code.google.com/p/busware/source/browse/trunk/SD0/Firmware_VZ/vzfeeder/vzfeeder.pl)

If I run the script I get the following error:

```
Can't locate POE.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/per /5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5  /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at   
./vzfeeder.pl line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./vzfeeder.pl line 6.
```

How can I start function/method on the console I hope you can help me?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you, that a Perl module (think of a library) used in the script is not installed on your system.

If you take a look at your script you will find statements starting with "use" at the beginning of it. Those are the modules referenced.

You will have to find out, which package of your package management system (deb, rpm?) contains them and install them accordingly.

Answer (score 7):

POE is a CPAN module that implements an event loop.  You'll probably want to install POE to get this program working.

I don't know much about the Raspberry Pi, but if it's anything like any other linux distro, you can either install a package from your distribution's repository or use the `cpan` tool to download/install it from the CPAN site.

Edit:

According to Wintermute the incantation `apt-get install libpoe-perl` should help assuming that you're running the standard raspbian.

Comment: Assuming that he's running the standard raspbian, `apt-get install libpoe-perl` should fix it.